# Вертикальное JS меню, прокручивающееся вместе с контентом, но в определенном диапазоне

Tags: jquery, меню, html, javascript, css

Вопрос до боли избитый и древний, но почему-то хороших решений не нагуглилось...

Итак, есть сайдбар. *Сайдбар по высоте может быть больше, чем экран.* Хочется избавиться от полос прокрутки внутри сайдбара, так как это ужасно неудобно. Вывод — нужно прокручивать сайдбар вместе с контентом. Но при прокрутке к концу сайдбара он должен прилипнуть к низу экрана. Кроме того наверху есть шапка, на которую этот сайдбар не должен налезать. Такое поведение у блока навигации на [news.mail.ru](http://news.mail.ru).

Подскажите, есть ли готовые решения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот набросал быстренько: http://jsfiddle.net/EXAe5/2/

Поведение такое же, движения менюшки ограничены блоком контента.

Кода получилось многовато, завтра попробую уменьшить все это безобразие...

Answer (score 2):

Еще такой [вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/jyGVe/). По мотивам [Fixed Floating Elements](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/)...

**UPD** По поводу готового решения:

- jQuery plugin. [ScrollToFixed](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed)
- Обсуждение на SO: [Fixed Floating Element Stop at Footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102776/fixed-floating-element-stop-at-footer)
- [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZczEt/9/) из ответа

Правда кода в плагине дополна, но работает как надо...

Comment: см. upd...

Comment: Думаю, что ТС опять скажет, что при большой высоте сайдбара, [это опять не подходит](http://jsfiddle.net/ZczEt/1330/).

Comment: ну Math.min(...) там добавить вероятно достаточно. у тс, похоже, есть свое решение. смысл в вопросе в таком случае?..

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, ему видней. Может это была внегласная проверка на проф. пригодность? ))

Answer (score 1):

Не плохо было бы увидеть структуру html, т.к. [примерчик, я конечно вам сделал](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/ygKSp/), но вот подойдет ли он вам - не факт. Хотя, там всё придельно просто и адаптировать под свою разметку, не должно составить труда.

---

**UPD** В общем, как вариант, [можно попробовать так сделать](http://jsfiddle.net/ygKSp/3/).

Comment: Не совсем. Если добавить еще итемов, то пример не сработает. Собственно из-за этого и проблемы.

Comment: @Zelta, если у вас возможен вариант, когда высота сайдбара больше, чем высота контента, то [это поправимо](http://jsfiddle.net/ygKSp/1/). Только в таком случае, на мой взгляд такая операция бессмыслена, ведь с таким же успехом (как в примере), высота сайдбара, может быть выше высоты страницы. Тогда средняя часть сайдбара - не будет доступна пользователю.

Comment: Ну тут вообще что-то странное получилось... Оно не работает не только когда высота сайдбара выше высоты страницы. Оно вообще не работает...

Comment: @Zelta, Работает, просто я вам показал, лучай крайний для вашей ситуации. И посмотрите UPD в моем ответе.